# How to re-ID polygons with sapply instead of for loop

Tags: polygon, r

I have a line of code that renames the id's of polygons in a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` by directly manipulating the `ID` slot of the polygon. I'm a bit slow when it comes to `sapply`, having used `for` loops for at least 20 years. Anyhow I have a piece of code that works using a `for` loop, but its really slow. I would like to replace it with a `sapply` command but can't figure it out. My code looks like this:

```
for(v in 1:nrow(SPoly)) {
    SPoly@polygons[[v]]@ID <- SPoly@data[v,3]
}
```

Can anyone suggest an `sapply` implementation of same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sapply` won't be faster in this case. Try `spChFIDs` instead (package `sp`):

```
SPoly <- spChFIDs(SPoly, as.character(SPoly@data[, 3]))
```

From `?spChFIDs`:

> change feature IDs in spatial objects
>
> **Description**
>
> When the feature IDs need to be changed in SpatialLines* or
>   SpatialPolygons* objects, these methods may be used. The new IDs
>   should be a character vector of unique IDs of the correct length.

Comment: Works brilliantly - and almost instantaneous. Fantastic. Thank you!